# PowerShell script to modify Azure data factory trigger time

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory

I am wondering if there is any PowerShell script which can help to modify the timestamp of the existing ADF trigger. I want to change the time of my pipeline trigger in UAT as we don't have permission to do that manually from portal.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger
   [-Name] <String>
   [-DefinitionFile] <String>
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-DataFactoryName] <String>
   [-Force]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

The Set-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger cmdlet creates a trigger in a data factory. **If you specify a name for a trigger that already exists, the cmdlet prompts for confirmation before replacing the trigger.** If you specify the Force parameter, the cmdlet replaces the existing trigger without prompting for confirmation. Triggers are created in the 'Stopped' state, meaning that they don't immediately begin invoking pipelines that they reference.

Refer this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/set-azdatafactoryv2trigger?view=azps-8.1.0) for sample example and syntax.